# The "zero" of energy and density of states

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I know that the only thing that matters is difference of energies, and not the value of the energy itself.

But I misunderstand something when it is linked to density of states.

Imagine a gas of particles in a box of length $L$, volume $L^3$.

We can compute the density of states $g(E)$ by counting the number of modes in $d^3k$ (we use periodic boundary conditions to describe the wave function).

Then we find $g(E)$ by saying that $g(E)dE=g(k)dk$ and using the relation between $E$ and $k$.

But here I don't see where we would have done an hypothesis on the "zero" of the energy.

Indeed the only two things we used are :

1. The volume occupied by a state in the $k$ space which is $(\frac{2 \pi}{L})^3$
2. The relation $dk=\frac{dk}{dE} dE$, so the relation $\frac{dk}{dE}$.

But (1) doesn't depend at all of the zero of the energy arbitrary chosen and (2) also if we take a photon for example ($E=h \omega + cte$ so $dE=hd\omega=h.c.dk$).

So, finally in a system $g(E)$ doesn't depend on the origin of the energies **but** the energy of a system must depend of a reference so there is something I don't get.

For example when we have an electrostatic potential, we **arbitraly** choose that the energy at infinity is $0$.

---

---

The example I am struggling with is when I want to compute the average energy of a phonon gas.

I need to calculate : $<E>=\int g(E) dE n_B(E) E$

I have computed $g(E)$ with the method described above.

$n_B(E)$ is the Bose Einstein distribution. In this distribution, the energy is fixed by $\mu$. Indeed, $n_B(E=\mu)$ is the average occupation of particles for a value of energy $\mu$, and $\mu$ is well defined because it is the **variation** of energy of a system when you add to it a single particle (which is well defined). So we use this value of $\mu$ to fix the constant of the energy of the system.

Finally, here $g(E)$ doesn't follow any convention of "zero" of energy but $n_B$ is linked to $\mu$, so the zero of energy is fixed by $\mu$.

My question :

In the example :  the 0 of energy of the bose einstein statistic is fixed by the potential $\mu$ but the 0 of energy of the density of states doesn't seem to be fixed. So how the quantity $g(E).n_B(E)$ can have a sense if the energies appearing in thoose two functions don't have the same "origin".

Comment: Can you point out the question you have? "Could you help me to understand all this?" doesn't tell us what the issue is.

Comment: In the example :  the 0 of energy of the bose einstein statistic is fixed by the potential $\mu$ but the 0 of energy of the density of states doesn't seem to be fixed. So how the quantity $g(E).n_B(E)$ can have a sense if the energies appearing in thoose two functions don't have the same "origin".

Comment: If you ever used $E \propto k^2$ anywhere in your derivation of $g(E)$, then the zero of energy of $g(E)$ is fixed. (i.e. it is zero when the kinetic energy is zero)

Comment: I didn't.

I work with phonons at low energies, so $E=h\omega (+ cte)$ and $\omega \approx v_s k$, so $g(E)dE=g(k)dk=4\pi * \frac{dk}{(\frac{2 \pi}{L})^3}=\frac{V}{4 \pi^2} \frac{dk}{dE} dE = \frac{V}{4 \pi^2} \frac{dk}{hd\omega} dE$

So it doesn't depend on any convention on the energy.

Comment: What is your expression for $g(E)$ explicitly? (In terms of no quantities besides constants and $E$ itself.)